# Problems with running bat file, which locks a file, through a python script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

When I run my python script it runs the bat file. This works fine until I attempt to lock the folder. I use the bat file for both unlocking and locking the folder. I just use my python script to run the bat file. The bat file works fine when I run it from file explorer but gives this error message when I run it from the python script:

```
Access is denied.
File not found - Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
Folder locked
```

The last message says it is locked but the folder is not.

I run the bat file from the python script using these two lines:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'filepath/FolderLocker.bat'])
```

the `.bat` file is attempting to run these two lines when the error messages show up:

```
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
```

&

```
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
```

I don't fully understand the command prompt commands and how they work.
The code in the bat file is:

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder Locker
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER

:CONFIRM
echo Would you like to Lock the Folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM

:LOCK
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End

:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%==Password_Here! goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End

:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end

:MDLOCKER
md Locker
echo Locker created successfully
goto End

:End
```

Comment: All your 'command prompt commands', have a built-in usage and help information. At the Command Prompt window enter the command followed by `/?`. This site is not here to do that for you, research your own code.

Comment: Change the `@ECHO OFF` to `@ECHO ON` so you can see which line in the batch file is causing the error. It looks like you're using the `attrib` command incorrectly. At the command line type `attrib /?` to get help on correct usage of the command.

Comment: Compo I have done my own research and have even tried your method in the past but have found no answers to my problem. but i would love to hear your method if you have one of fixing this very simple problem that only requires a /? command to see the parameters for the...my problem isn't with parameters it is within integrating this with a python script the only thing attrib /? tells me are the parameters that the attrib command can have and what each does

Comment: @martineau the access denied happens when i try to rename or move the folder. and the file not found is a result of that error

Comment: Sounds like the Python script doesn't have admin rights (so the batch file doesn't have them when it's run by the script). Sorry, I don't know how a Python script could raise its own privilege level).

Comment: that is what i was thinking as well...once i get some more free time i am going to look more into this